# Give a useful denial of each statement.

Tags: proof-verification, logic

> Give a useful denial of each statement.
>
> a) T is not bounded or T is compact. (Assume that T is a fixed objet.)
>
> b) Ali is studying Mathematics and English.
>
> c) If Ahmad was here, he can answer your question.

My attempt:

a) T is bounded “and” T is not compact.

b) Ali is not studying math “or” English.

for (c) I know that, $\lnot (P \implies Q)$ is $P \land \lnot Q$, so I think the answer is:

c) Ahmed was here “and” he can not answer your question.

Is that true? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, these are all fine.  The only changes I would make are just for additional clarity., for example (b) I would have said "Ali is not studying math or Ali is not studying English" so as to not confuse what you wrote with "Ali is neither studying math nor is he studying English."  Unfortunately, commonly spoken English is often imprecise and slightly ambiguous.  There is also the question of verb tense usage in (c)., I think it may be more correct to say "Ahmed *is* here and he can not answer your question."

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you so much.